# how to convert string(which in array form) to array/object

Tags: php

I am doing payu automation refunds. In that after sending the request am
       getting response as

```
$res =  Array (
    [status] => 0
    [msg] => Refund FAILURE - Invalid amount
    [error_code] => 105
    [mihpayid] => 569611073
   )
```

But if check gettype($res) its coming as string...
       Here am not able to get key and value pairs using

```
$res['status'] or $res['msg']
```

Its giving

```
A PHP Error was encountered
     Severity: Warning
     Message:  Illegal string offset 'status'
     Filename: pgrefunds/pgrefunds.php
     Line Number: 296
```

suggest me how can get the kay value pairs...

Comment: what if you do a `var_dump($res)`. what do you get then?

Comment: I think it's an output of `print_r` the array you showing in `$res`

Answer (score 1):

In the PayU documentation (https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Request-and-Response-format/110) you can read this line:

> Web Service API responds back in PHP **serialized string** by default.

So you must unserialize the content before using it. Depends on the configuration the content can come as JSON or in "array" form (serialized). Depends on the case you must use `json_decode` or `unserialize`.

Comment: If you do a print of $res what string do you get exacly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting a serialized response. You should unserialize the string.

```
$resArr = unserialize($res);
$resArr['status'];
```

**EDIT**

As other answer show the other option is to you `json_decode()`

```
$resArr = json_decode($res);
$resArr['status'];
```